# Nuget Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.* version 5 not supported in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

I'm trying to install the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` version 5.0 but it is not supported on the .NET Core 3.1 MVC application. While changing on the csHTML page the changes are not reflecting on the local host web application even after refreshing the page.

[image]

Comment: Well, I'd suggest either upgrading your project to ASP.NET Core 5, or downgrading the version of that package.

Comment: Dot Net Core 5 ??? From where shall I get .Net Core 5, I know the latest version is 3.1, if I downgrade the project then those will not support Azure Webapp for delpoyment

Comment: @DS .NET 5 (**not** .NET Core 5) went live a few days ago. Update VS to 16.8.1

Comment: (Yes, they've rebranded to "ASP.NET Core in .NET 5" to avoid it sounding too much like .NET Core 5 is a thing.) See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-net-5/

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto My Visual studio version is  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.5

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation is a pure .net 5 lib and dropped support for .net standard 2.1. Vote for the [ticket to support version ranges in Pakcagesreference](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6566), to ignore incompatible update like this. Camilo posted how to go one

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: you **cannot** install .NET 5 packages to a .NET Core application.
You have 2 options:

1. Update Visual Studio (if you haven't already) to 16.8.x and update your project and all dependencies to .NET 5, OR
2. Keep using .NET Core 3.1.x versions.